# Experiencing high memory utilization after upgrade to SDL Web 8.1

Tags: web8, web8-cu1

We are experiencing high memory utilization after upgrade to Web 8.1. Our websites are running on Windows Server 2012 + Java 8 + SDL Web 8.1 + .Net Framework 4.6.1 + IIS 8.5
we have upgraded sites without recompile and same application consuming nearly 200 MB more memory after upgrade. Our old infrastructure was Windows Server 2008 + Java 7 + SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 + .Net Framework 4.5.2 + IIS 7.5

Can anyone help me on following queries?

1) Is the memory consumption increase expected with Web 8.1 upgrade? or it could be due to Java, IIS and OS upgrade ?.

2) How can we optimize the memory usage of Web 8.1 based .net applications? 
3) Please suggest any tool or way so that we can identify which component is the reason behind high memory consumption.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you upgraded "as is" and are not using the microservices approach? This would decouple Tridion from the webapp